# Optimal permutation of vector's entries for minimizing distances between vectors

Tags: combinatorics, optimization

Recently I faced the following problem.

Say, given two $n$-dimensional real vectors, $v_1$ and $v_2$.
It is needed to minimize euclidean distance between $v_1$ and $v_2^{\langle i_1, i_2, \ldots, i_n \rangle}$, where $v_2^{\langle i_1, i_2, \ldots, i_n \rangle}$ is a vector obtained from $v_2$ by permutation $(i_1, i_2, \ldots, i_n)$ of its entries:

$\| v_1 - v_2^{\langle i_1, i_2, \ldots, i_n \rangle} \| \to \min {\text{  by all permutations } (i_1, i_2, \ldots, i_n)  } $

Comment: Hint: sort them.

Comment: Sorting sometimes helps.
I tried to sort both vectors and calculate the norm by corresponding entries (obtained in sorting).
Unfortunately, this method does not always minimize the norm.

Answer (score 0):

You can formulate this is a linear assignment problem as follows.  Let binary decision variable $x_{i,j}$ indicate whether $(v_1)_i$ is matched to $(v_2)_j$.  The problem is to minimize $\sum_{i,j} ((v_1)_i-(v_2)_j)^2 x_{i,j}$ subject to
\begin{align}
\sum_j x_{i,j} &= 1 &&\text{for all $i$}\\
\sum_i x_{i,j} &= 1 &&\text{for all $j$}
\end{align}

Sorting both vectors should yield an optimal solution.  If you have a counterexample, please provide one.

Comment: Thank you, I'll consider your suggestion.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1983442/help-with-a-minimum-distance-permutation-problem) for a proof when the objective is to minimize the sum of absolute values.  I think only the triangle inequality is needed, so it works for sum of squares, too.

Comment: I'll see it soon